# Spring Boot, Issue using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using NetBeans 8.1, i have a SpringBoot project that has as dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

They are all properly downloaded in Dependencies.

The project has 3 java classes and an interface to extend JpaRepository<>

```
@Entity
public class Journal implements java.io.Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String title;
private LocalDate created;
private String summary;

public Journal() {
}

public Journal(String title, LocalDate created, String summary) {
    this.title = title;
    this.created = created;
    this.summary = summary;
}
// getters and setters
}
```

---

```
@Controller
public class JournalController {

@Autowired
JournalRepository repo;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("journal", repo.findAll());
    return "index";
}

}
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootJournalApplication {

@Bean
InitializingBean saveData(JournalRepository repo) {
    return () -> {
        repo.save(new Journal("text1", LocalDate.now(), "date1"));
        repo.save(new Journal("text2", LocalDate.now(), "date2"));
        repo.save(new Journal("text3", LocalDate.now(), "date3"));
        repo.save(new Journal("text4", LocalDate.now(), "date4"));
    };
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootJournalApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

---

```
public interface JournalRepository extends JpaRepository<Journal, Long>{}
```

---

Under *src/main/resources -> templates* i have a *index.html* file with a tag -html lang="eng-US" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org- :

```
<html lang="en-US" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Spring Boot Journal</h1>
        <ul class="timeline">
            <div th:each="entry,status : ${journal}" >
                <li th:attr="class=${status.odd}?'timeline-inverted':''" >
                    <div class="tl-circ"></div>
                    <div class="timeline-panel">
                        <div class="tl-heading">
                            <h4> <span th:text="${entry.title}">TITLE</span> </h4>
                            <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
                                    <span th:text="${entry.createdAsShort}">CREATED</span> </small></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tl-body">
                            <p> <span th:text="${entry.summary}">SUMMARY</span> </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

On the html tag i have the error : **Attribute with the local name "xmlns:th is not serializable as XML 1.0**. If i try to run the project and go to the *http://localhost:8080/* page i have a **Whitelabel Error Page** and in the netbeans console i have **org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'createdAsShort' cannot be found on object of type 'com.example.Journal' - maybe not public?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error it self says enough: there is no such field `createdAsShort` in class `com.example.Journal`. According to what you've shown definitely there is no such field in your class.

Comment: Thanks, i was following the example from a book, i removed that line and it works, still from the .html file i always have "Attribute with the local name "xmlns:th is not serializable as XML 1.0" in the html tag and in every th:, also i'm not able to use suggestions in th: tags like i would in a jsf xhtml with "xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html". Is that supposed to happen? Is this a NetBeans issue? Because working without  suggestions/autocomplete may be an issue for me.